# Use css to move sidebar to the left side of the page

Tags: css

How do I move the sidebar so it is on the left side on the screen like the rest of the pages in Hebrew the site? 
Only on this page it is showing incorrectly on the right side: 
http://goldenhersh.co.il/he/product/%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A8-%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%9F-%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%91-%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9F-%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%99/

Comment: Take `!important` off the css values **please**. They're not even necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you change

```
#container {
    float: left !important; //float left is wrong here
    width: 76% !important;
```

with

```
 #container {
    float: right !important; //use float right instead
    width: 76% !important;
```

The result looks as following
[image]

I suggest you inspect the`<div id="container">...</div>` with Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools, so you can see the styles applied.

Comment: I have float: right !important; in my rtl.css file but for some reason it isn't working on this page. Why?

Comment: If you able are able to unminify your CSS styles, you would see exactly which Rule from which file sets the wrong `float: left !important`. Is there another file where you set the `float: left !important`? Do you get _float: left_ or _float: right_ if you inspect the element.

Comment: how do I unminify to see where the rule is coming from? I've deleted it from my css file and cleared the caches so I don't why it is still showing.

Comment: I assume you are using wordpress. Perhaps you have installed a plugin like https://wordpress.org/plugins/bwp-minify/. If so disable the plugin and clear the cache. Then check your page again.

Comment: there was an extra } that was breaking my css. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it's working now. :)